# Help with a member function calculating distance

Tags: c++

I need to report the distance between the argument point and the current point. I tried to insert an image to show the current point and the argument point. But i am not allowed to post images.

I don't know how i would work out the distance. Any ideas would be great .

I have a triangle and the line along the bottom is x and at the right hand side of a line is a point. the line up the side is y and there is a point at that like.

Comment: Have you wrote some code? If this is homework you should tag it like that.

Comment: What distance you're looking for? In what context you want to use it?

Comment: Are you struck at how to do calculation or writing a program for it in C++ ?

Comment: I am stuck on how to do the calculation i can write it in c++ when i know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 3):

If you meant [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) on a plane, try something along the lines of this:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

double distance(Point p, Point q) {
    return sqrt((p.x - q.x)*(p.x - q.x) + (p.y - q.y)*(p.y - q.y));
}
```

Please note that this is very rough and doesn't check for overflows and stuff like that.

Comment: You forgot to take the square root.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Euclidean Distance. but i have done a pythagoras theorem function .

Comment: In that case, you're all set - the distance is the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle. All you need to do is figure out the lengths of the other two sides.

Comment: Ok so i just need to do an equation to work out x and y? How would i figure out the lengths of x and y? because the pythagoras function is to come after this function.